# Impossible to localize an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, xcode6

Localization is driving me crazy!

I would like to have my application in english, and in french. So here is what I have in my project settings:

[image]

To begin, let's try to translate my storyboard:

[image]

Because my storyboard is in english (base language?), I've just ticked Base and French.

I guess Localizable Strings are easier to give to translators, so I choose "Localizable Strings"

Now my problem is the following:

When I change the text of a label in the base storyboard

[image]

Nothing happens, the text is not changed when launching the app.
If I edit Main.strings, nothing happens.

It's like another storyboard is used (a past one), but if I check my Finder, I don't have any other storyboard (even hidden).

Last weird thing, I have this in my "Copy bundle ressources":

[image]

If I remove it and add it again, the result is still the same.

I don't know which storyboard my app is using, I can't find it in Finder, and my "Copy bundle ressources" section is telling that a storyboard is missing, even if I add it again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you delete the App completly from the device or simulator and try again?

Comment: Removing the app seems to work on simulator, but not on device.

Comment: Is french the main language of your device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved the problem by clean project and clean build folder and then in edit schema I setted configuration by change Run Options by changing application language and application region (in my case Italian) as writed [here](http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/)